# Extracting json from an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of users, and every user has its data.

I'm trying to extract user number 1 (id=1) and then save it in `useState`. After that, I want to map it and print it as li.

so far I've had no success.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './myCss.css';
import { useState ,useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import Page2 from './Page2'



function Page3() {


  const [users,setusers] = useState([])
  const [user,setUser] = useState({})
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      
      let resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      setusers(resp.data); 
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

// In this function I try to print the information

```
 const getData = () =>
  {
    let myUser2 = users.filter(x=>x.id==1)
    setUser(myUser2)

    {
      user.map((item,index)=>
      {
        return <li key = {index}>{item}</li>
      })
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className = "styles">

      <input type = "button" value = "Get Data for comp 1" onClick = {getData}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page3;
```

Comment: I can track that `getData` is called when the input is clicked and updates the `user` state. I don't follow what you are trying to do from there.

Comment: You are using map on `user` which you have defined the initial value as an object (in `getData`), is that really expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot print data in `getData` which is an event function. Instead of that, you should add it to JSX.

Besides that, `user` is a single user and `users` are a list of users. `filter` is not fit for your case in finding a single user, I'd suggest that you use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead. `find` will return an object, so you don't need to use `map` for renderings.

```
//`user` is an empty object, so we need to make sure it has data inside `user` with `Object.keys`
{user && Object.keys(user) > 0 && <li key={user.name}>{user.name}</li>)}
```

Full possible modification

```
function Page3() {


  const [users,setusers] = useState([])
  const [user,setUser] = useState({})
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      
      let resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      setusers(resp.data); 
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []); 
 
  const getData = () =>
  {
    let myUser2 = users.find(x=>x.id==1) 
    setUser(myUser2)
  }


  return (
    <div className = "styles">
      <input type = "button" value = "Get Data for comp 1" onClick = {getData}/>
      <ul>
         {user && Object.keys(user) > 0 && <li key={user.name}>{user.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page3;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I have a question why would you want to map through a state that contains only one value. I see no point in this, however in case you will store more information inside userstate you may try something like the following:

```html
const getData = () => {
  let myUser2 = users.filter(x=>x.id==1)
  setUser(myUser2)
}

const printUser = user.map((item, index) => <li key={item + index}>{item}</li>

  return (
    <div className = "styles">
      <input type = "button" value = "Get Data for comp 1" onClick = {getData}/>
      <ul>
      {printUser && printUser}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page3;
```

Comment: thanks for the answers
In user there is more than one object,
name, email, id
and more,
I asked the question to know how to properly retrieve the information